# How to remove a row from a list based on the value of a column

Tags: haskell

I have a list of Data Type (SlcCustomer) which I created:

```
[SlcCustomer {slcCustName = "Xena Gamble", slcCustID = 1, slcCustAge = 27},SlcCustomer {slcCustName = "Brooke Castaneda", slcCustID = 2, slcCustAge = 80}]
```

I got this output using the PRINT function on my result.

Now I need to FILTER this, I want to remove any row that has a slcCustAge <= 20 ... is there a way to use the built-in filter type thing and somehow check for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be using list comprehensions:

```
let sourcelist = [SlcCustomer {slcCustName = "Xena Gamble", slcCustID = 1, slcCustAge = 27},SlcCustomer {slcCustName = "Brooke Castaneda", slcCustID = 2, slcCustAge = 80}]
let resultlist = [x | x <- sourcelist, slcCustAge x <= 20]
```

This will filter the list as you desire, with the filter condition specified after the comma.

Alternatively, you can use `filter` to do the same thing as:

```
let resultlist = filter (\x -> slcCustAge x <= 20) sourcelist
```

You can just return `resultlist` from your function, or print it depending on what you want.

Comment: I don't want to print it, I need to store the new list and pass it to my next function.

Comment: Then just assign it to another variable. I will edit my code to clarify that.